# Is there a way to see the string version of a parameterized cypher query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neography

In Ruby on Rails, using NeoGraphy, I'm constructing a parameterized cypher query and getting back a result.

```
@results = $neo.execute_query(query, parameters)
```

Using gon, I put all these to the client and checked them out in the javascript console:

```
gon.results = @results
gon.search_query = query
gon.search_parameters = parameters
```

gon.search_query is just what I see in the .rb file, so I guess that means cypher takes that and takes the parameters and then creates the query.  **Can I get to the string version** of the query that must be created by using the parameter values?

The reason I want this is so that I can paste it into the neo4j web admin console tool and tweak it.

Thanks!

Comment: There is never a string query, the parameters are used during the execution at runtime. But we will add support for parameters in the webadmin console and shell with 2.0

Comment: Oh that would be really cool!  When's 2.0 coming?  Also when I grabbed the full query from my puts statement in the terminal (see my comment below) and paste it in the webadmin console, I got a syntax error.  

It wanted an equals sign I think instead of the colon after the words_item 
START me = relationship:edges(likes:(*donut*) 

Can you please point me to documentation on relationship:edges ?

Also can I paste the entire query into the neo4j console?  It doesn't seem to let me... I am having to paste in line by line then finally ; and return for it to run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to accomplish that is to write your own print method that given the query and the parameters would print the expanded query. And you can call it before / after the $neo.execute_query

Comment: also, we will hopefully be adding a DumpToString method to the execution result, which is there is Scala.

Comment: Cool. Thanks both.  RaduK, that's what I ended up doing and it's working great.  I puts it so I can see it in the ruby terminal.  thanks!